# Question about error getting when making a calculator by python

Tags: python

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Calculator")
window.geometry('350x500')
num1 = Label(window, text='Input :').grid(column=0, row=0)
num2 = Label(window, text='Input :').grid(column=0, row=1)
res_label = Label(window, text='output :').grid(column=0, row=2)
entry1 = Entry(window)
entry1.grid(column=1, row=0)
entry2 = Entry(window)
entry2.grid(column=1, row=1)
def add():
    res_text = 'result =' + str(float(Entry.get()) + float(Entry.get()))

def minus(event):
    res_text = 'result =' + str(float(num1.get()) - float(num2.get()))

def slice():
    res_text = 'result =' + str(float(num1.get()) / float(num2.get()))

def multi():
    res_text = 'result =' + str(float(num1.get()) * float(num2.get()))

def result():
    res_label.configure(text=res_text)

def press(value):
    value1 = str(value)
    Entry.insert(INSERT, value1)

btn1 = Button(window, width=15, text='1', command=lambda: press(1)).grid(column=0, row=3)
btn2 = Button(window, width=15, text='2').grid(column=1, row=3)
btn3 = Button(window, width=15, text='3').grid(column=2, row=3)
btn4 = Button(window, width=15, text='4').grid(column=0, row=4)
btn5 = Button(window, width=15, text='5').grid(column=1, row=4)
btn6 = Button(window, width=15, text='6').grid(column=2, row=4)
btn7 = Button(window, width=15, text='7').grid(column=0, row=5)
btn8 = Button(window, width=15, text='8').grid(column=1, row=5)
btn9 = Button(window, width=15, text='9').grid(column=2, row=5)
btn0 = Button(window, width=15, text="0").grid(column=0, row=6)

btn_plus = Button(window, width=15, text="+", command=add)
btn_plus.grid(column=4, row=3)
btn_minus = Button(window, width=15, text="-", command=minus).grid(column=4, row=4)
btn_multi = Button(window, width=15, text="*", command=multi).grid(column=4, row=5)
btn_slice = Button(window, width=15, text="/", command=slice).grid(column=4, row=6)
btn_res = Button(window, width=15, text='=').grid(column=2, row=6)
```

This is my code, but when I press run and press 1 button on my popup, I am getting an error saying,
"TypeError: insert() missing 1 required positional argument 'string'" Could anyone tell me why I am getting this code?

Comment: because You haven't passed an argument to the function, seems that `INSERT` is not an index

Comment: It is not because of that, it is because you lack self, in the call of your function. The method insert() is a method of the Entry() class and requires to be called with a self argument

Comment: You call insert from the class `Entry` so it needs an instance. You need to call it from the instance: `entry1.insert(...)`...

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because as I said in my comment, insert() is a method from the class Entry(). So as an instance method it needs to be called with a self argument, the self meaning the specific instance. The way to call this method with a self argument is to call it directly with the specific Entry class instance you want to call it from.

In your code there are two problems. First you call the method on the class object 'Entry', and not on the class instance Entry() which is why you see that error as previously explained. Secondly you don't use your specific Entry instance that you created before. So it will not insert text where you want it to.

You can try this insert() method:

```
def press(value):
    value1 = str(value)
    if  '.!entry' == window.focus_get().__str__():
         entry1.insert(INSERT, value1)
    elif '.!entry2' == window.focus_get().__str__():
        entry2.insert(INSERT, value1)
```

---

Explanation:

You choose based on which Entry() instance is focused where you want to input text. If entry1 is selected in your window you insert in this entry, if this is entry2 you insert in that entry.

The method window.focus_get() tells you which instance element is currently focused in the window. The dunder method .**str**() returns the element name as a string, which is in this case '.!entry' if you selected entry1 and '.!entry2' if you selected entry2

---

Note:

By the way, same in your add() function you call the get() method on your class object and not your specific instance